# Importing multiple layers in QGIS: ERROR: Too many connections: max 64

Tags: qgis

I get this error in the terminal when I open more than 40 layers in a project and QGIS eventually crashes. It doesn't happen when I open them into a completely new project. How can I avoid this?

Comment: More detail, please.  Does this problem happen *only* with one *specific* project?  You say that it doesn't happen when you open the 40+ layers in a new project, but does the problem occur when you save the new project and then reopen it?

Comment: The error shows up either if the layers are imported into a new project or into an existing project. However, if I import them into my existing project QGIS crashes, which is not the case when they are imported into a new project.

Comment: Please re-read your comment.  The two sentences are at odds with each other.